# Efficiency with the functional paradigm

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Since functional code by definition avoids mutability as best as it can, one could write a stateful program by unfolding state from the previous over time. So, I'm writing a game in F# purely in the functional style, and of course games tend to have lots and lots of state. I essentially use records for game objects (such as players), and I simply map over all these states to get the next state. This works very nicely. But, as my game gets more and more structurally complex, I'm worried that it will get sluggish because of all that copying each update. I'm wondering how I might try to avoid these pitfalls in the future (not right this moment since it's not much of an issue yet, though).

So are there any significant optimizations used in the functional style that F# doesn't do for me, specifically related to copying large chunks of data when only small portions might be changed? Also, is there anything that F# has that I can use to my advantage in this same way?

One more thing -- here are my two main concerns that might not even be true. I'd love to get these straightened out:

1. Garbage collection. Since I end up copying thousands of records a second, there's got to be a massive amount of object generation, all of which is extremely short-lived since I just throw away old state. This seems to be a probable reason for the short but barely noticeable jumps in the game every second or so.
2. Is F# efficient at copying records with all but a few fields updated? If it's not, how can I improve efficiency myself?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question.  Try focusing on one issue per question (preferably something concrete -- try writing something which is slow and then ask about how to write it faster, that way we have something specific with which to work).

Comment: I would localize hot path of your app, separate it from the rest of the code and then I would make it mutable inside.

Comment: na, dont worry. the main obstacle to perf is understandability. As a first approximation, any understandable code will end up faster than any other ununderstable code, no matter what method is used. of course to squeeze the last bit of juice, and only after properly measuring timings, you have to use mutation, but that should be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So are there any significant optimizations used in the functional
>   style that F# doesn't do for me, specifically related to copying large
>   chunks of data when only small portions might be changed?

Is it really the case that you are copying "large chunks of data"?

Normally, the advantage of immutable data structures is that you don't need to copy them. For example, if you have a functional Map, you may "update" some data, but most data remain untouched and are shared between the old and thze new map, as well as the bigger part of the map itself.

Comment: Well, I thought that the advantage of immutable data structures is that you can't change them. In some cases, wouldn't you need to copy everything over to get the next state? Otherwise, how would you get this next state?

Comment: @Jwosty, read what he said. The unchanged data is shared between the old and new map (same applies for lists), so the only bit that isn't shared is the bit you're changing (which wouldn't be shared anyway). Of course there are edge cases (eg, changing the 'wrong' end of a list).

Comment: Ah, I understand. I guess there isn't really much to worry about then! :)

Comment: @Jwosty Indeed you should when you *don't* use functional data structures. For example, arrays of structs or something like that.

Comment: Haha, 3 months of my project without mutability, haha!